# Extjs - Align icon on tab title

Tags: javascript, css, extjs, extjs4

Using tabpanel in Extjs, I would like to set an icon on the tab beside the title using setIconCls;

here is what i get:

[image]

How can i align it to the left?

```
Ext.getCmp('updates').setIconCls('notification_icon');
```

--

```
.notification_icon{  
    background-image: url("../icons/notif.png") !important;   
    width: 40px !important;
}
```

I tried align and margin etc... it only moves to the right, while it should be before letter 'N'.

Comment: That icon doesn't look like it's 40px wide...

Answer (score 1):

Cannot exactly think without knowing your element structure. but here is some few options you can try.

1. Add right margin to icon - `margin-rignt:10px;`
2. Add left margin to text (if your text inside an element) - `margin-left:10px;`
3. Add minus left margin to icon - `margin-left:-10px;`
4. Use float left with icon - `float:left`
5. Use icon as background image for text element with left padding.
6. If any of these not works, you can use table with one row and two cells to position text and icon.

Answer (score 1):

How did you get this result in the first place? Just changing the `background-image` property (and nothing else) should work out of the box... You've most probably overridden Ext's CSS somehow, you should try to fix that.

With Ext's vanilla CSS, `margin-left` is working to move the icon horizontally. Otherwise, by default, icon spans are absolutely positioned, so you can try playing with the `left` attribute.